# Is it possible to get pyautogui to locate images and click in a virtual Machine?

Tags: python, automation, virtual-machine, pyautogui

I am trying to create a bot that will perform tasks on a virtual machine. Some of the tasks involve navigating a web page, clicking, typing, locating images on the screen.

I was able to successfully make the bot on my work pc but I am struggling to get some of the functions from `pyautogui` to work on a virtual machine.

Was wondering if anyone had success using `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen` or  `pyautogui.click()` in a Virtual machine? For now I am using task scheduler to start the program and when I watch the program run the mouse is invisible and it is getting stuck locating images.

```
itemNotThere = ('itemDoesNotExist.png',.9) #image name and confidence

def check_valid_search(imageName):
    """ Return pixel locations of an image or 1 if not found. """
    r = None
    while r is None:
        try:
            r = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
                    imageName[0], grayscale=True, confidence=imageName[1])
        except:
            r = 1
    return r

print(check_valid_search(itemNotThere))
```

Comment: if you want to navigate web pages then maybe you should use `Selenium` which can control web browser and it commonly used to navigate web pages.

Comment: Link to unofficial docs: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Comment: Yea, I wasn't looking for the selenium solution because I am looking to automate tasks outside of web browsers as well. I found that you can use the locate function in pyautogui to search for an image in an image. What I ended up doing was taking a screenshot of the virtual machine and creating an image object with y = pyautogui.screenshot() and then using r = pyautogui.locate(imageName[0],y, grayscale=True) to locate the pixel values of the image I wanted to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot of the virtual machine with pyautogui.screenshot and search the screenshot with the locate function.

```
itemNotThere = ('itemDoesNotExist.png',.9) #image name and confidence

def check_valid_search(imageName):
    """ Return pixel locations of an image or 1 if not found. """
    r = None
    while r is None:
        try:
            y = pyautogui.screenshot()
            r = pyautogui.locate(imageName[0],y, grayscale=True)
        except:
            r = 1
    return r

print(check_valid_search(itemNotThere))
```